# перенести макет сайта PSD в OpenCart

Tags: cms, opencart, psd

Здравствуйте, ребята. Кто-нибудь знает, как перенести макет сайта PSD в opencart? Много есть по WordPress, но по Opencart хорошего не нахожу

Comment: Вам бы сначала верстать, только потом думать о переносе.

Comment: ну PSD макет уже есть

Answer (score 0):

На opencart 2x все шаблоны стоит в

```
/catalog/view/theme/(dafault по умолчанию)
```

можете прямо клонировать под другой name `dafault` и поменяв с админки: система > настройки > редактировать > (вкладка) магазин > Шаблон магазина: Сменит на свой
вы можете начать верстать из свой psd в этот шаблон

Comment: что за файлы tpl и никаких html и php файлов почему то нет?

Comment: .tpl это и есть `html ` и `php` html и php тесно взаимосвязаны а tpl просто правила хорошего тона

Comment: ну вот, у меня есть PSD макет, я что-то не понимаю с чего начинать, с другими CMS как-то все проще

Comment: у opencart еще проще по словам программистов который хоть раз работал там итак все понятно, да и имя папок и файлов говорят сами за себя. Например начните с шапки: `/common/header.tpl`